# When to use Sagas in microservice pattern

Tags: transactions, microservices, saga

Let's say I have a couple of microservices, area and store each with their own unique data domain.
The store contains a reference to it's parent area's id and name. Users also have the option to delete/update areas. When the user pulls down a store after it's parent area has been deleted I obviously don't want them to be given a reference for a area that no longer exists.

I am wondering what the best approach is in a simple use case such as this in terms of ensuring data consistency. All research I've done points to using SAGAs, but they seem complicated to implement and like overkill for such a simple scenario. Is there a better way to approach things in terms of design patterns or architecture, or is this kind of unneccssary complexity just inherent to microservice architectures ?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you're not going to get anything stronger than eventual consistency across microservices without a saga or something that's going to be at least as complicated.

With that in mind, every decision to put two operations (e.g. "delete area" and "get store" and/or "get store's area") into separate microservices is at some level a bet that "we won't need these operations to be more than eventually consistent", and losing that bet means you get to implement at least one saga (this isn't technical debt: the more appropriate financial analogy is option-writing/shorting volatility).

So if you don't want to implement a saga, it might (especially earlier in a project) be worth rethinking microservice boundaries: domain driven design practices may help with that rethink.